# How can I create a slideshow using jQuery by looping images through an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, api

I am new and still learning so if you notice anything basic that I should know, please call it out.

Firstly, this is what I have:

```
$(function () {
  $.ajax({
    url: "",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function (results) {
      var photosArray = new Array();
      var allPix = results.data._included.media;
      for (var i = 0; i < allPix.length; i++) {
        var mediaNumber = allPix[i];
        var photosHtml = "<div>";
        photosHtml += "<img src='{0}'/>".replace("{0}", mediaNumber.photos.largest);
        photosHtml += "</div>";
        photosArray.push(mediaNumber.photos.rectangle);
        $(".images").append(photosHtml);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

In the above code, I am accessing an API call to get images.

Secondly, I want to use the image url's I get from that call to create this slideshow:

http://jsfiddle.net/SxN8g/17/

The problem is that in that slide show everything is in an array and that's how images are being shown.  How can I use the above solution in my function to create this slideshow for my images?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex14/fadeinslideshow.htm

var mygallery2=new fadeSlideShow({
    wrapperid: "fadeshow2", //ID of blank DIV on page to house Slideshow
    dimensions: [978, 308], //width/height of gallery in pixels. Should reflect dimensions

```
of largest image
    imagearray: [

        ["images/1.jpg", "#", "", "","test1"],
        ["images/2.jpg", "#", "", "","test2"],
        ["images/3.jpg", "#", "", "","test3"],
        ["images/4.jpg", "#", "", "","test4"]

    ],
    displaymode: {type:'auto', pause:3000, cycles:10, wraparound:true, randomize:true},
    persist: false, //remember last viewed slide and recall within same session?
    fadeduration: 500, //transition duration (milliseconds)
    descreveal: "always",
    togglerid: "fadeshow2toggler"
});
```

as you can see this runs off of an array that you could manipulate. hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks but I am looking to see how I can get my images url's to appear in the imageArray...